# Creating custom codec from text file at runtime in Python

Tags: python, encoding, runtime, codec

I have a script that reads bytes from a binary file, decodes them using a custom encoding, and writes the characters to a text file. Currently, I'm just using a predefined encoding I made by making a modified copy of the cp1252 encoding with the decoding_table altered to fit my needs.

So like:

```
decoding_table = (
    'A'
    'B'
    'C'
    'D'
    etc.
)
```

However, I want the user to be able to define their own custom encoding. I was thinking I could do this by having the program create the encoding at runtime, and reading in a text file in the program folder to define the decoding_table variable in a blank codec.

So I'd have a text file organized like:

```
a
b
c
d
etc.
```

In other words, imitating the format of the decoding_table in a codec.

I realize I could probably just imitate this by creating a pair of dictionaries at runtime and using dictionary lookups to decode and encode bytes, but is it possible to generate a custom codec at runtime in Python? And if it is possible, would  doing this so that I could use codec.encode() and codec.decode() be better or worse than just using dictionary lookups?

Answer (score 0):

You have most (or all) elements, so a lookup table (a list) takes less time and memory (usually, I really do not know if you are using a strange encoding) then dictionary (answer of last question).

I think you can do exactly like Python, check e.g. coded cp1252:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Lib/encodings/cp1252.py

As you can see, the code is very simple, and I assume that it is also optimized.

Comment: Modifying this file is what I've done already. What I'm asking is if I can generate a codec like this at runtime and use user input to define the decoding table.

Comment: The code is pure Python, so it is created run-time. You need just to create the list before to use, and possibly create a unique name at every change from user. You just need to parameterize such file.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure I entirely understand what you're suggesting, but the first sentence made me realize I could write a function in the codec itself that I can call from other modules to alter the encoding and decoding tables at runtime. Easy, and seems to do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved my own question. I changed my modified codec to replace the definitions of decoding_table and encoding_table with a settables() function.

So it now looks like:

```
def settables(lookup_table):
    global decoding_table
    global encoding_table
    decoding_table = lookup_table
    encoding_table = codecs.charmap_build(decoding_table)
```

This way, the codec starts without either encoding or decoding tables. In my main module, I imported the custom codec and called custcodec.settables(lookup_table), where lookup_table is a string. This seems to work, as the decoded text files it produces are identical to those produced by my original codec where the lookup table was predefined in the file itself. From here it should be no problem to read the characters for the lookup table from a text file.